# OpenMP arbitrary reduction (merge)

Tags: c++, openmp

I want to use OpenMP to collect some data. For that, I check many candidates and collect only those that satisfy some conditions. The simplified example would be the following.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

class DataPoint {};

DataPoint random_data_point() {
    // generate random data point
}

bool test(DataPoint r) {
    // do something
}

int main() {
    constexpr int num_iterations = 10000;

    set<DataPoint> good_points;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(???)
    for (int iter = 0; iter < num_iterations; iter++) {
        DataPoint r = random_data_point();
        if (test(DataPoint))
            good_points.insert(r);
    }

//  ...

    return 0;
}
```

The question is how to use OpenMP efficiently. My idea is that each thread collects its own data (in the example above - its own set) and then, after all of the thread finished, their sets are merged.

Note 1: my iterations are very independent (as in the example above), so OpenMP should be helpful.
Note 2: in the real programme, I use more complicated data structure than set. (In fact, it is a convex hull of the data points.)

Comment: You don't have the code here so it is hard to tell, but you need to be careful about how you generate random numbers inside "random_data_point", there is a lot of complexity in parallel random number generation, and simply calling the serial generator is extremely unlikely to be the optimal solution!

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that

Comment: For some background you could look at this paper from the Supercomputing Conference a while back http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf Note that this is implemented in Intel MKL (which is available gratis to everyone), other libraries may also have it, or something similar. (As ever, "The best code is the code I don't have to write" :-))

Comment: Hmmm actually this might be an issue indeed. My programme runs fine on machine with Intel CPU. But it is muuuuuuch slower on the one with AMD. I think I need to educate myself on parallel random number generation with OpenMP...

Comment: The issue is parallel random number generation in general. OpenMP is merely the way that you are generating parallelism. As before, find a math library and use it. Good random number generation is a complicated field so exploit someone else's brains!

Comment: It feels strange that I cannot generate random numbers (no need for crypto-secure or anything) in multithread application with just standard tools of C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern OpenMP allows you to define your own reduction functions, so you should be able to achieve this that way should you want to, though, realistically, for something this simple it might be easier just to write code along these lines  (untested, typed into this answer, not compiled :-))

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    set<Data_Point> thread_good_points;
#pragma omp for nowait
    for (int iter = 0; iter < num_iterations; iter++) {
        DataPoint r = random_data_point();
        if (test(DataPoint))
            thread_good_points.insert(r);
    }
#pragma omp critical
    good_points.merge(thread_good_points);
}
```